# how to create the effect flipping paper android

Tags: android

I have one problem in my program.
I am creating one screen including:

- groups(include 1 picture (4) + 1 textview (3)) and they are stacked
- when I slide right or left hand (above or below)

  - the group will fly and disappear
  - and the other group appears

This is what it should look like:

### [image: my screen]

What's a good way to do this?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

Comment: @RobinHood: not page curling, because i want to groups fly out and disappear when slide top-right, bottom-right or top-left, bottom-left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extends `FrameLayout` and modify the `onMeasure`, `onLayout`.

Comment: hi, i'm newbie, Can you give me example ?

Comment: it's too complex to write code here. onMeasure determin child view's size, onLayout tell them where they go. that's almost all of andorid view framework.